# Catch the Interface in the String then Store it in a Variable

Tags: regex, ansible, cisco

Basically my goal is to catch the cisco interfaces (ie. Gi1/0) from the string that I used to store in variable intf. I am puzzled how I am going to construct my regex with set_fact that will catch interface from intf variable.

Based from regex101.com this regex will match Gi1/0 interface: 
`^\w+(-\w+)?\d+(([\/:]\d+)+(\.\d+)?)?$`

I tried below code to catch the interface Gi1/0 for example, and store that in variable storehere, but only encountered errors.

```
  - name: Catch interface only ie. Gi1/0 and store in storehere variable
    set_fact:
      storehere: "{{ intf | regex_findall(^\w+(-\w+)?\d+(([\/:]\d+)+(\.\d+)?)?$) }}"
```

This is my full code:

[Full Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxZAo.png)

[Execution W/o Regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htaTt.png)

[Error W Regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK3lW.png)

Comment: There are missing quotes in your code, the ansible error like of suggests this: try this `"{{ intf | regex_findall('^\w+(-\w+)?\d+(([/:]\d+)+(.\d+)?)?$') }}"`

Comment: Also this regex seems too general for Gi1/0 pattern, `'Gi\d+\/\d+'` would suffice, if there are more slashes `'Gi\d+(\/\d+)+'` would do it.

Comment: Hi engrheis, welcome to SO! Please, please don't put images of code and error messages in your questions. It means that other people who might be searching for your same problem are not able to match on the error message or code blocks. It also is a huge pain to read code in images. Good luck!

Comment: @geckos , I tried the missing quotes but still got same error: "found unknown escape character" . I tried to replace all \ with double backslah \\, error vanished but just lead  to "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ..."

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel yeah this is noted..just my first time posting hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your full code seems to imply that there might be multiple lines in the output. Presumably they all follow the same pattern, and the data that you need from each, is just the first column - the interface name? If so, does this fulfill your needs:

```
- set_fact:
    interfaces: "{{ interfaces | default([]) }} + {{ [ item | regex_search('^([^ ])+') ] }}"
  loop: "{{ rl00.stdout_lines | first }}"
- debug:
    var: interfaces
```

(Note: in your example, rl00.stdout_lines contains a list, with a list of output lines as its only element. That looks a little odd and I am not sure if there are cases where other elements would be present. This answer should work for the example data you provided, but may run into problems if other elements are returned.)

This:

- Loops through the lines contained in the **first** list contained in your rl00 registered variable
- Filters the first non-space chars from the beginning of the string
- Adds them as an item in the 'interfaces' list

That should leave you with a list containing interface names. You can then treat them how you like, so for example, if you need them on a single, space separated line, you could then:

```
- debug:
    var: interfaces | join(' ')
```

Comment: Yeah your right, I just need the values for the first column which will list all the interfaces that have ATT in the description. I include your code, but still got this: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ (interfaces | default([])) }} + {{ [ item | regex_search('^([^ ])+')] }}): expected string or buffer"}

Comment: Hmm - looking again at your example without regex, I see that rl00.stdout_lines contains an list, with a list of the output lines as its only element. That is not what I would expected, but I have edited my answer to reflect the output you provided.

Comment: Sounds good :) I was able to pull the interface..Only problem now its having a double quote. Just need to eliminate that so i can use ie.Gi1/0 for example as an interface to my next task.                                          
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [R1-192.168.98.135] => {
    "interfaces": [
        "Gi1/0"
    ]

Comment: My next task looks like this                                                                                      
 - name: SHOW INTERFACE STATUS W/ DESCRIPTION 
    ios_command: 
      commands:
        - show int {{ interfaces }} desc | i [ ]+up

Comment: It seems that double quote is just part of the default debug. Though when I ran my next task: TASK [SHOW INTERFACE STATUS W/ DESCRIPTION] ****************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [R1-192.168.98.135]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "show int [u'Gi1/0'] desc | i [ ]+up\r\n            ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\n\r\nR1#"}

Comment: 'interfaces' is a list, not a string, because your example implied that there might be more than one interface returned in the output of ios_command. Therefore, 1) there are no actual '"'s in each element, 2) for your next task you would need another loop, to loop through each returned interface in 'interfaces'.

Comment: I owe you some drinks @clockworknet !! Thanks for all the help. I have a much better understanding now.